# Disable dragging the object when it is on the right position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got a problem on disabling drag when "item" is on the right position. I tried to use `e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject)`, but it seems nothing happens. I think that it's not functioning because the event that I want to remove is not `dragObject but the function that it returns...please help;
Here's my code

```
function dragObject(indx1:int,indx2:int):Function { 
return function(event:MouseEvent){
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.currentTarget); 
item.startDrag(); 
var topPos:uint=item.parent.numChildren-1; 
var itemSound:Sound = new Sound();
itemSound.load(new URLRequest("sounds/"+dirArray[indx1]+indx2+".mp3"));
if(!activeSound)
{
    itemSound.play();
    activeSound=true;
}
activeSound=false;
item.parent.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}
function releaseObject(indx:int,origX:int,origY:int):Function{ 
return function(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(e.currentTarget); 
    item.stopDrag(); 
    trace(indx);
    if(indx==1)
    {
      if (box5_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        if(insideBox5==1){
            item.x=73;//2nd locations
            item.y=298;
            myBell.play();
            }
        else if(insideBox5==2){
            item.x=90;//3rd locations
            item.y=267;
            myBell.play();}
        else{
            item.x=32; //1st locations
            item.y=268
            myBell.play();
        }
        insideBox5++;
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragObject);
        correctItems++;

      } 
      else { 
        item.x=origX; 
        item.y=origY; 
        myBoing.play();
      } }
```

I've updated this post and included where I called it, it's actually on my main function. Here's the part on calling functions dragObject and releaseObject

```
var itemImage:Loader = new Loader();
    //loads the file on location...
    itemImage.load(new URLRequest("images/"+dirArray[indexc[count-1]]+index[count2]+".png"));//load random image from random images folders
    var functionOnDrag:Function = dragObject(indexc[count-1],index[count2]);
    index.splice(0,1);
    var functionOnRelease:Function = releaseObject(indexc[count-1],tempx-42,tempy);
    trace(index);//trace index
    trace(count);//trace count
    count++;
    pb[i].addChild(itemImage);//adds the picture on the picBox
    pb[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,functionOnDrag);
    pb[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,functionOnRelease);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would properly format your code (indentation).

Comment: waw your functions returning functions are so horrible ;) I think it would be better to place your vars indx1, indx2, indx, origX and origY in some class vars and use real named functions as event handlers than anonymous functions. On the code you provided, there is nowhere you call the dragObject and releaseObect methods.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm an as3 rookie. I've added where I called it. By the way, I don't know how to _place my vars indx1, indx2, indx, origX and origY in some class vars_

Answer (score 0):

You have very specific code... Here working example of the draggable object, that will be stopped if it reaches right side of the screen. As you can see, in my example I don't use constructions like you (Function generate another function). Pay attention to `onDown`, `onMouseUp` and `onMoveCursor`methods:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class StackOverflow extends Sprite {

        private var _dragObject:Sprite;

        public function StackOverflow() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function setup():void {
            var randomObject:Sprite = createObject();

            addChild(randomObject);

            //Place it in center of scene
            randomObject.x = stage.stageWidth >> 1;
            randomObject.y = stage.stageHeight >> 1;

            //Register mouse down for drag
            randomObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
        }

        private function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
            //By moving mouse will check current position
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMoveCursor);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

            _dragObject = e.currentTarget as Sprite;

            _dragObject.startDrag();
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMoveCursor);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

            if (_dragObject != null) {
                _dragObject.stopDrag();
                _dragObject = null;
            }
        }

        private function onMoveCursor(e:MouseEvent):void {
            //Assert that right side is end of the screen
            if (_dragObject.width + _dragObject.x >= stage.stageWidth) {
                trace("Gotcha!")
                onMouseUp(null);
            }
        }

        private function createObject():Sprite {
            var result:Sprite = new Sprite();
            result.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            result.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
            result.buttonMode = true;
            result.tabEnabled = false;
            return result;
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            setup();
        }
    }
}
```